# What's the difference between javascript methods assigned to properties of "this" vs. methods defined on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I understand that the purpose of methods assigned as properties of "this" in a constructor is to make them privileged in that they can access private attributes and methods like this:

```
var Book = function(newFirst, newLast){

  //private attributes
  var author_first = newFirst;
  var author_last = newLast;

  //public attributes
  this.puAuthor_first = newFirst;
  this.puAuthor_last = newLast;

  //public privileged methods (accessing private attributes)
  this.getAuthor = function()  {
    return author_first + author_last;
  }

}
```

but what's the difference to objects that inherit from Book compared to methods assigned to the prototype object like this:

```
Book.prototype.nonPrivilegedGetAuthor = function() {
   return this.puAuthor_first + this.puAuthor_last;
}
```

?

So my question is 2-fold:

1) When this object is inherited from via Prototypical Inheritance, both getAuthor() and nonPrivilegedGetAuthor() are inherited, right? And the idea is that getAuthor() will be copied to the new object, whereas nonPrivilegedGetAuthor() will be available through the prototype chain, with the benefit of not being copied, right? What are the costs aside from not being able to access private members?

2) What about Classical Inheritance? Specifically, will the public non-privileged method assigned as a property of the prototype object get inherited? What considerations should I be concerned with there? Without doing a few more things when you inherit, you'll basically have a gap in the prototype chain that skips over one object, right? We have to connect the child object's prototype chain to the Book--how do we do that? What do we do to properly inherit, and what pitfalls can happen if we don't?

Comment: 1) There's no such thing as inheritance in Javascript        2) There's no such thing as public and private in Javascript        3) nonPrivilegedGetAuthor will have access to the object properties because it is a method of the object        You need to read up on prototype but its basically a chain of objects that are used to resolve method scope. There's very little difference between getAuthor and nonPrivilegedGetAuthor in terms of scope.

Comment: i guess i gotta ask a simpler question because I have no answers to accept on this one. i'll do your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a function to a class' (this word being used lightly) prototype, all of the instances of that class will use the same function.  On the other hand, if you define the function using the this keyword, you will only be defining for that instance.  The benefit to prototypes is the fact that you can have one function which works for all instances of the class instead of defining a new function each time.

As far as inheritance is concerned, I must defer to Douglas Crockford:  http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html.  As far as making variables private, there is no way to truly make a variable private in a cross-browser way, but you can fake it.  I have done it with jPaq's Color objects and others have written about it.  Once again, I would suggest looking at what Douglas Crockford has to say:  http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html.  Though my approach is a bit different, if you want to make members private, it is not impossible in JavaScript.  Here is an example of how to implement private variables in a cross-browser fashion:

```
var Book = (function() {
  var key = {};

  var Book = function(newFirst, newLast) {
    // Private variables stored in an object literal.
    var $ = {
      author_first : newFirst,
      author_last : newLast
    };

    // Public privileged method for accessing private variables.
    this._ = function(aKey) {
      if(aKey === key)
        return $;
      throw new Error("The _() function must be called internally.");
    };
  };

  // Public accessor method.
  Book.prototype.getAuthor = function() {
    var $ = this._(key);
    return $.author_first + " " + $.author_last;
  };

  return Book;
})();

var bookA = new Book("Chris", "West"),
    bookB = new Book("Douglas", "Crockford");
alert(bookA.getAuthor());
alert(bookB.getAuthor());
```

That is the same way that I implemented private members in jPaq.